# Test Prep Question: Finding unknown value (r)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is another math question I'm not very confident with:

A state is redistricting its legislature. Each district is given 3 state senators and 1 state representative. In addition there are *r* at-large representatives without a district. If this process results in 27 senators and 27 Representatives, what is *r*?

These are the steps I used to find *r*:

1. Find number of districts. We are given the *number of senators* and the *number of senators per district*. Number of districts = 27 / 3 = 9
2. We know the number of representatives is 27 and the *number of representatives per district*: *9 + r = 27* so *r=18*.

Answer: *r=18*

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, your solution is corrrect.